# Installing Viki on Vim 7.4.52

Tags: vim, plugins, wiki

I'm following Swaroop's Byte of Vim, and have reached the chapter on personal information management, where it says to install the Viki plugin. The instructions are as follows (and I have no real idea of what is going on, but):

1. Download multvals.vim [2] and store as $vimfiles/plugin/multvals.vim
2. Download genutils.zip [3] and unzip this file to $vimfiles
3. Download Viki.zip [4] and unzip this file to $vimfiles (make sure all the folders and files under the 'Viki' folder name are stored directly in the $vimfiles folder)

After this I open a new text file in vim and run the commmand

```
:set filetype=viki
```

but I get a whole slew of errors. I've tried clearing out my ~/.vim folder and reinstalling everything, along with tlib this time as specified on the [Viki vimscript page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=861), and extracted the version 4.0 viki.vba instead of using the version 4.08 zip file, but I'm still getting errors about non-existent functions:

```
Error detected while processing home/user/.vim/ftplugin/viki.vim:
line 100
E117: Unknown function: tlib#balloon#Register
```

I don't really know what's going on, and am quite a new Vim user, so please be patient. Right now my ~/.vim directory tree looks like this:

```
.vim
├── autoload
│   ├── genutils.vim
│   ├── tlib
│   │   ├── eval.vim
│   │   ├── list.vim
│   │   ├── notify.vim
│   │   ├── persistent.vim
│   │   ├── progressbar.vim
│   │   ├── TestChild.vim
│   │   └── vim.vim
│   ├── tlib.vim
│   ├── viki
│   │   ├── enc_latin1.vim
│   │   └── enc_utf-8.vim
│   ├── viki_anyword.vim
│   ├── viki_latex.vim
│   ├── viki_viki.vim
│   └── viki.vim
├── colors
│   └── molokai.vim
├── compiler
│   └── deplate.vim
├── doc
│   ├── tlib.txt
│   └── viki.txt
├── ftplugin
│   ├── bib
│   │   └── viki.vim
│   └── viki.vim
├── plugin
│   ├── 02tlib.vim
│   ├── genutils.vim
│   ├── multvals.vim
│   └── viki.vim
└── test
    └── tlib.vim
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't appear to have installed all the dependencies properly. For instance `tlib#balloon#Register` references an autoload function Register in `~/.vim/tlib/balloon.vim` however that file does not appear to be there

Comment: The file is supposed to be `~/.vim/autoload/tlib/balloon.vim` (Forgot the autoload part in the last comment)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out I didn't extract the tlib.vba correctly

Answer (score 0):

The info is outdated. You need to install a current versions of tlib and viki from:

- https://github.com/tomtom/viki_vim
- https://github.com/tomtom/tlib_vim